# Como filtrar dados de um JSON com JS?

Tags: javascript, json

Galera, queria saber como faço um "select" dentro de um arquivo JSON usando JS.

Exemplo:

[image: Esse é o exemplo]

Tenho uma tabela abaixo usando dados vindo de um arquivo JSON, mas queria fazer um filtro para quando clicar em pesquisar, ele soltar na tabela o resultado.

Obs: Eu não manjo muito de frameworks de JS, mas caso for mais fácil, por mim tanto faz.

Como exemplo usem esse JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "nome": "Pedro",
        "console": "ps2",
        "preco": "200"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "nome": "Val",
        "console": "ps1",
        "preco": "50"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "nome": null,
        "console": "xbox",
        "preco": "2000"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "nome": "Flavio",
        "console": "one",
        "preco": "1000"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "nome": "Giovanna",
        "console": "xbox98",
        "preco": "300"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "nome": "Luana",
        "console": "xbox",
        "preco": "200"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "nome": "Pri",
        "console": "ps2",
        "preco": "100"
    }
]
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yakubixi/4/edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma vez que crias a tabela a partir desse JSON o melhor é fazeres cache desses elementos do DOM (`<tr>`) e associalos ao teu objeto inicial para poderes trabalhar com eles depois.

Ou seja: se juntares a cada um desses objetos uma propriedade, por exemplo `DOM`, podes depois (sem esforço para o Browser) ir buscar o elemento que queres e escondê-lo caso o filtro não se aplique a ele.

Um exemplo seria:

```
data.map(function (pessoa) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.keys(pessoa).forEach(function (valor) {
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = pessoa[valor];
        tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    table.appendChild(tr);
    pessoa.DOM = tr;
    return pessoa;
});
```

Portanto partindo do teu JSON que eu chamei de `data`, podes mapeá-lo para ter em cada objeto (chamei de `pessoa` no código) o conteúdo original **mais** uma nova propriedade `pessoa.DOM = tr;`.

Assim podes depois filtrar somente o JSON sem ir procurar ao DOM, o que é muito mais eficiente. Depois podes usar classes de CSS para esconder o que não queres:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var prop = select.value;
    var val = input.value;
    data.forEach(function (linha) {
        var valor = linha[prop];
        if (valor && linha[prop].indexOf(val) < 0) linha.DOM.classList.add('esconder');
        else linha.DOM.classList.remove('esconder');
    });
});
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/cjwoumey/

Answer (score 5):

Fiz um código simples em JS puro com base no seu form. É bem simples, teria que aprimorar:

Sendo `json` a variável com o json dos seus dados, `select` a combo onde os valores são o nome das colunas(propriedades no caso) contidas no json e `query` o elemento *text* do seu form. Acesse a demo mais abaixo para entender.

O código do botão que filtra(*"Pesquisar"* no seu caso) os dados:

```
document.getElementById("filter").onclick = function() {
    var result = json.filter(function(item) {
        return item[select.value] == query.value;
    });
};
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kdgLyy/)**</kbd>

A ideia é usar o [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) do javascript.

Outros exemplos com o filtro de string sendo do tipo [contains](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kdgLyy/1/), [startsWith](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kdgLyy/2/) e [endsWith](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kdgLyy/3/).

[Demo atualizada com o json postado.](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kdgLyy/4/)

[Demo atualizada com geração da tabela.](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kdgLyy/6/)

Comment: Dont, seria possível você deixar esses códigos funcionais? Não consegui entender muito bem os exemplos.. Tipo, mostrar o retorno do filtro em uma tabelinha, só para eu conseguir ver o que aconteceu melhor..

Comment: @GiovanniBernini porque nao mete voce um `console.log(...)` em cada linha para ver o que precisa? ou melhor, porque nao faz por debug e ve o que se passa em cada linha?

Comment: @GiovanniBernini coloquei uma demo utilizando seus dados, e também [essa demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j9kdgLyy/5/) com o código todo comentado. Recomendo abrir o console e ir debugando linha a linha(F10) para entender - já deixei um `debugger` lá de propósito.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Eu consegui entender melhor agora o código, mas tenho algumas duvidas, pq o resultado não aparece? Foi intencional?

Também não sei como debugar pelo console (Acredito que esse console seja o do navegador, porem não sei como debugar nele), web é meio novo para mim. Vou dar uma pesquisada aqui sobre isso, mas valeu desde já!

Comment: @GiovanniBernini sim, foi intencional. Usei o comando `console.log` pra exibir os resultados. Pra debugar pelo console, você abre o console com a tecla F12 e depois dá um *Run* na página. Ao carregar vai parar no *breakpoint*, que é o comando `debugger` no código. Depois é só debugar com F10 ou F11, passando o mouse em cima das variáveis para ver os valores. Sempre bom também pesquisar os comandos que você não conhece, sugiro esse site: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Aah, tem dar o Run, por isso não tava aparecendo nada no console, entendi. Como eu faria para pegar esse [result] e descarregar em uma tabela?

Comment: @GiovanniBernini pra criar uma tabela com os dados você tem que montar os elementos e exibi-los no html. Você pode fazer isso do jeito mais difícil com html puro ou com jQuery, qual você prefere?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown's Prefiro com jQuery, vai ser mais complicado de eu entender, mais eu me viro. Valeu mesmo aí Dont, puta ajuda que você está me dando!!

Comment: @GiovanniBernini dá uma olhada na última demo que postei.